# Change Number of Bins with Seaborn Countplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have this code in Python:

```
df = pd.read_excel('data (1).xlsx')

x = np.array(df['biceps circumference (cm)'])

ax1 = sns.countplot(x="biceps circumference (cm)", data=df)
```

Where df is my data frame and "biceps circumference (cm)" is a column. I'm using seaborn's countplot function to make a frequency distribution. But, I want to change the number of bins and their size in the plot. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Formulate title in form of question.

Answer (score 3):

For a distribution [Histplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html#seaborn.histplot) will be more fitting and gives more flexibility.

Countplot can not show distributions it only can show absolute counts of categories and across categories.

```py
bins = "auto"
df = pd.read_excel('data (1).xlsx')
x = np.array(df['biceps circumference (cm)'])

ax1 = sns.histplot(data=df, x="biceps circumference (cm)", bins=bins)
```

[image]

Comment: This is the right answer although I'm not sure what the second sentence means.

Answer (score 1):

````
df = pd.read_excel('data (1).xlsx') 

x = np.array(df['biceps circumference (cm)']) 

ax1 = sns.displot(x="biceps circumference (cm)", data=df, height=7, aspect=1.6, bins=20, Kind = hist)```
````

Comment: height*aspect gives you the width.